# What is meant by Distributed for a gradient boosting library?

Tags: xgboost, distributed, boosting

I am checking out XGBoost documentation and it's stated that XGBoost is an optimized **distributed** gradient boosting library.

What is meant by distributed?

Have a nice day

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that it can be run on a [distributed system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing) (i.e. on multiple networked computers).

From XGBoost's [documentation](http://dmlc.cs.washington.edu/xgboost.html):

> The same code runs on major distributed environment(Hadoop, SGE, MPI) and can solve problems beyond billions of examples. The most recent version integrates naturally with DataFlow frameworks(e.g. Flink and Spark).